# how to solve Browser errors were logged to the console?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, mobile-website

PageSpeed Insights is showing this error message for my wordpress website ([MyBGMI.Com](https://mybgmi.com/)
I can't fix this problem. To be very honest can't understand the problem.

**Errors logged to the console indicate unresolved problems. They can come from network request failures and other browser concerns. Learn more

Source
Description

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode') at data:text/javascript;base64,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:1:200**

I tired figured out the issue but did not understand anything. Just checked the page with chrome browser developers tool.
And where i found two erros. but can't understand how to fix them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2dmJ.png)

Comment: Don't worry about the second error, it's unrelated to the first. If you want to fix it read about putting a "favicon" into your site.  Your first error suggests you have a proprietary plugin or theme that limits how often people can download stuff. (NOTHING in WordPress core uses this nasty base64 encoding of Javascript.) If you can figure out which plugin it is ask the developer. By the way, base64 encoding of Javascript is one script-kiddie trick to try to conceal malware. I would never tolerate it on a site I operated.

Comment: I have deleted the script. could you please help me out to put counter before button appearing?

Answer (score 0):

This is `base64` encoded JavaScript (usually bad when found on WordPress site)
(you can decode it online here: https://www.base64decode.org/)

Decoded it says:

```
var downloadButton=document.getElementById("download");
var counter=40;
var newElement=document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML="You can download the file in 40 seconds.";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement,downloadButton);
id=setInterval(function(){
    counter--;
    if(counter<0){
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton,newElement);
        clearInterval(id)
    }else{
        newElement.innerHTML="JUST WAIT "+counter.toString()+" SECONDS."+"YOUR BGMI 2.3 DOWNLOAD LINK IS GENERATING"
    }
},1000)
```

it appears that newElement.parentNode is null and that's what's causing the error.

if this is your code, and a desired code-piece on your WordPress website - try changing `if(counter<0){` into `if (newElement.parentNode && counter<0) {` . otherwise, find where this is coming from, and remove it from your code base.

**Update**

Try this:

```
var downloadButton=document.getElementById("download");
var counter=40;
var newElement=document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML="You can download the file in 40 seconds.";
var id;
if (downloadButton && newElement.parentNode) {
    downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement,downloadButton);
    id=setInterval(function(){
        counter--;
        if(counter<0){
            newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton,newElement);
            clearInterval(id)
        }else{
            newElement.innerHTML="JUST WAIT "+counter.toString()+" SECONDS."+"YOUR BGMI 2.3 DOWNLOAD LINK IS GENERATING"
        }
    },1000)
}
```

Comment: changed the part from  if(counter<0){ into if (newElement.parentNode && counter<0) {
but didn't worked.

Comment: still facing error

Comment: even I deleted the code but it still showing errors.

Comment: maybe try clearing the cache? there can't be an error in a code that is no longer served...

Comment: with updated code the countdown function was not working.  But I tried with that to get rid of the error. Ok I am trying once again.

Comment: the previous error gone and new error occurred " 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Progress! try posting a new question for the new problem. If you found the answer helpful - please mark it a such. Also, please note the comment from @O. Jones - he's right about not using base64 in your code.